# How do you calculate the total resistance here?

Tags: operational-amplifier, resistors, inverting-amplifier

I have three resistors in an inverting operational amplifier and I should compute the Vout with the total resistance of those 3. Should the Rf/k be considered connected in parallel with those 2 Rf? My professor wrote that it's like this but I don't understand why it is so.

[image: Resistances]

My professor wrote that it's like this but I don't understand why it is so.

[image: Professor's solving]

Comment: Hey! Good question. Approach the question from the different side. You don't know what Vo is, how would you approach it? Even if you don't get the final answer, show what you already can!

Comment: Most simple solution: Apply the star-triangle transformation

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I will try to guide you through the logic, I hope it will help you in your further tasks. It's all about how you approach it and how you think about it. Once you know it, every task will feel similar. Most of it is just tossing numbers and letters around.

Let's start with the basics: Op Amp outputs whatever it needs/can to make inputs equal. Thus, inverting input is also 0V (virtual ground).

If one side of R1 is 0V and another is Vi, then there is a current across R1. It's

> I1 = Vi/R1.

So far so good.

[image]

Since op amp inputs don't source/sink current (ideal op amp), all the current must also flow through the left Rf, since current doesn't appear out of nowhere and disappear into nothing. Therefore, voltage across Rf_left is:

> Uf_left = Rf * (Vi/R1) = Vi * (Rf/R1)

So, for the Rf_left one side of it is at 0V (op amp input), another side is at Uf_left = Vi * (Rf/R1).

How much current flows through the Rf/k? Well, it has the same voltage across it as Rf_left, because both of its sides are on the same voltage levels. Therefore, **they're effectively parallel to one another**. So we have k times smaller resistance for the same voltage. Therefore, k times larger current. You can always do the math if you want, it will yield exactly this result.

> I_rf_k = k * If_left = k * I1 = k * Vi/R1.

The total current of the Rf_left and Rf/k has to flow via Rf_right. Thus,

> If_right = If_left + If_k = Vi/R1 + k * Vi/R1 = (k+1) * Vi/R1.
>
> Uf_right = If_right * Rf = (k+1) * Vi * Rf/R1.

This is voltage **across** Rf_right.

Now we figured out voltage across Rf_left and voltage across Rf_right, and we know that one side of Rf_left is zero.

> Vo = Uf_left + Uf_right = Vi* Rf/R1 + (k+1) * Vi * Rf/R1 = Vi * Rf / R1 *(k + 1 + 1) = Vi * (Rf/R1) * (k+2).

QED.

Moral of the story: consider currents. Makes a lot of stuff a lot more intuitive.

Comment: Please don't provide complete solutions to homework questions.

Answer (score 2):

### Given that someone else has made a complete answer, it seems reasonable for me to point out my nearly complete solution

<sub>Note that my original picture (below) showed only stage 1 and stage 2. I'm completing this answer to a greater degree because it demonstrates the approach of solving it pictorially rather than running through a stack of words and formulae.</sub>

**Hint** (as intended originally)

You can use Thevenin's theorem to solve this by converting the two resistors that form a potential divider on the op-amp output into a fixed attenuator with an equivalent output impedance: -

[image]

<s>I'll leave the rest to you. Let me know if you are having problems manipulating the math. The next step involves drilling down to the equivalent resistance of the two resistors in series and drilling down to the attenuator's much simpler formula. After that it's real-easy.</s>

It's really easy from here and almost insulting to propose it.